# Related to rand() function

Tags: codeblocks

```
For(i=0 to 10)
  printf(%d\t%d,rand()%100,rand()%100);
```

It always prints the same set of values.
Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: Please go through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: nothing to do with codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

The `rand()` function generates random numbers with a given "seed" number. When you dont specify the seed `rand()` will give you the same output every time.
To set a seed use `srand(time(NULL));` to make use of the computers internal clock to set the seed. Dont forget to include `time.h` in order to have access to the `time()` function.